# VBA | Range Sort by descending is still sorting in ascending

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Good day to all,

I have a dropdownlist for user to choose "ascending" and "descending", and a range of data in Worksheets("FullData") to sort by.

row A1 is the header.

Ascending works.

But not descending, even though the correct msgbox appear. It still sort in ascending.

Can anybody point out my error?

```
Dim uR As Range
Set uR = Worksheets("FullData").UsedRange
MsgBox "TEST SortBy = " & SortBy

If SortBy = "ascending" Then
    MsgBox "ascending"
    With Worksheets("FullData").Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange uR
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
    End With
    
ElseIf SortBy = "descending" Then
    MsgBox "descending"
    With Worksheets("FullData").Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlDescending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlDescending
     .SetRange uR
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
    End With
    
End If
```

Comment: When you run the code first time it I guess you selected "ascending" which is added to the [SortFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields) collection.  When you run it a second time you're not clearing the previous sort.  Use `.SortFields.Clear` before applying the new sort order.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it will store the previous sort info.